# Regex - find a word in string in which there's always one extra letter

Tags: c, regex

I'm writing a program in C that uses PCRE (perl compatible regular expression) to match a list of words in a string. The catch is that this is for a word search puzzle that i'm bruteforcing, and in order to make it harder for us to find the right words, each word has an extra letter (e.g CHARIOT is CH****ARIOT inside the string)

I've been trying to replicate this but i've only managed to get something similar with \w, which isn't efficient because this extra letter can be anywhere between the second letter and the second-to-last one.

[image]

I would really appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it can be between the second letter and the second to last one using a case insensitive match:

```
C[A-Z]*([A-Z])\1[A-Z]*T
```

**Explanation**

- `C[A-Z]*` Match a `C` and 0+ occurrences of a char A-Z
- `([A-Z])\1` Capture in **group 1** a char A-Z followed by a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to what is captured
- `[A-Z]*T` Match 0+ occurrences of a char A-Z and match a `T`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TNWjli/1)

You could also use `\w` instead of `[A-Z]` but that can also match a digits or and underscore.